# isEmpty() on an ArrayList results in false although its size is 0

Tags: java, arraylist, is-empty

In a test I inject a mock to another class which seems to work properly. However, when I check the ArrayList if it is empty the result is false although its length/size is 0. How can this happen and how can I solve this problem?

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Setter(onMethod_ = @SuppressFBWarnings({"EI_EXPOSE_REP2", "EI_EXPOSE_REP"}))
@Getter(onMethod_ = @SuppressFBWarnings({"EI_EXPOSE_REP2", "EI_EXPOSE_REP"}))
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyProperties.class)
public class MyConfig {

    private final MyProperties myProperties;

    private final GenericApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        Objects.requireNonNull(myProperties, "myProperties needs not to be null.");
        if (/*myProperties.getApps().size() == 0 || */myProperties.getApps().isEmpty()) {
            log.info("bla bla bla");
        } else {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my test class:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class MyConfigTest {

    @Mock
    MyProperties myPropertiesMock;

    @InjectMocks
    MyConfig myConfig;

    ApplicationContextRunner contextRunner;

    @Test
    void should_check_for_empty_apps() {
        contextRunner = new ApplicationContextRunner()
            .withPropertyValues("foobar.apps[0].name=", "foobar.apps[0].baseUrl=", "foobar.apps[0].basePath=")
        ;

        List apps = Mockito.mock(ArrayList.class);
        when(myPropertiesMock.getApps()).thenReturn(apps);

        myConfig.init();

        contextRunner.run(context -> {
            assertThat(apps.size()).isEqualTo(0);
        });
    }
}
```

The properties class:

```
@Slf4j
@Validated
@Data
@Setter(onMethod_ = @SuppressFBWarnings({"EI_EXPOSE_REP2", "EI_EXPOSE_REP"}))
@Getter(onMethod_ = @SuppressFBWarnings({"EI_EXPOSE_REP2", "EI_EXPOSE_REP"}))
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = MyProperties.CONFIG_PREFIX)
public class MyProperties implements LoggableProperties {

    public static final String CONFIG_PREFIX = "foobar";

    @Valid
    @NestedConfigurationProperty
    private List<MyEndpoint> apps = new ArrayList<>();

    @Data
    public static class MyEndpoint {
//        @NotNull
//        @NotEmpty
        private String baseUrl = "";

        private String basePath = "";

//        @NotNull
//        @NotEmpty
        private String name = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to mock an `ArrayList`. Just create a "normal" new one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
List apps = Mockito.mock(ArrayList.class);
```

When you mock a class, all of its method bodies are completely discarded. Methods with a non-`void` return type return the default value for that type. For `size()` that's 0 (default for `int`), but for `isEmpty()` that's `false` (default for `boolean`).

You can use `spy` instead of `mock` to get the actual implementation for methods you don't mock. That's also where the difference between `when(x.method()).thenReturn(y)` and `doReturn(y).when(x).method()` differ. The former actually calls the method but discards its result in favour of the mocked return value. The latter doesn't call the method at all (but isn't type safe).

Is there a reason you're mocking the array list? I don't see you using the array list as a mock at all.

Comment: It was an attempt because when I use `when(myPropertiesMock.getApps().isEmpty()).thenReturn(true);` I got `org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
Boolean cannot be returned by getApps()
getApps() should return List`.

Comment: You don't need to mock the list or its `isEmpty()` method. You already mock the result of `myPropertiesMock.getApps()`. Instead of returning a mocked `ArrayList`, just return a regular `ArrayList`. You can put any elements you like in there to satisfy your test's needs.

Comment: Well, that works as well. I wanted to verify the call to isEmpty() and this is only possible if apps is a mock: `verify(apps).isEmpty();` 
But maybe this is not necessary because I do `assertThat(myPropertiesMock.getApps().isEmpty()).isTrue();`

Comment: If you want to verify you can use `spy(new ArraryList<>)`. That works for non-final classes and non-final methods. It acts the same unless you mock out one of its methods, but even without mocking it allows you to verify calls. But verify only tests that calls are made, not what they return. That's what assertions are for, like you're doing now.

Answer (score 0):

‘app’ is a mock. You have to mock any method that you use, otherwise it retrieve type’s default value.